# Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined. Binding the grid fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am creating a MVC 5 application using kendo MVC grid. The data that i am pulling from the database is not binding to the grid. When I check the developer controls is see error Uncaught ReferenceError: kendo is not defined. I have also noticed that the action method specified in the grid doesnt fire. Looks like a jquery issue.

I have checked all my references and done the basic set to run kendo MVC. Not sure what the problem is

```
@model IEnumerable<CC.GRP.MCRequest.Models.TeamIn>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<CC.GRP.MCRequest.Models.TeamIn>()
    .Name("GridTeam")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamID).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(o => o.CountryCode);
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamName);
        columns.Bound(o => o.TeamDescription);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Groupable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Read(read => read.Action("Team_Read", "Admin"))
    )

    )
```

**Controller code**

```
   public ActionResult Team()
        {

            return View();

        }
        public ActionResult Team_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            return Json(mcrRepository.GetTeams().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

**Bundle.config**

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                     "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/kendo").Include(
                     "~/ Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jquery.min.js",
                     "~/ Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/jszip.min.js",
                     "~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.all.min.js",
                      "~/Scripts/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js",
                    "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/custom/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/custom/app.css"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/Site.css",
                    "~/Content/bootstrap.css"
                    ));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/kendo/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.common.min.css",
                    "~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.mobile.all.min.css",
                     "~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.min.css",
                     "~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.default.min.css",
                     "~/Content/kendo/2017.1.223/kendo.dataviz.default.min.css"
                     ));

            bundles.IgnoreList.Clear();

}
```

**Layout.cshtm**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/custom/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")


</head>
<body>

    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
            <div class="container-fluid">

                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="#"><img src="~/Images/Computacenter.png" /> </a>
                    <h1>MCR</h1>
                </div>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right text-center">
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-home" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Home</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Requests</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-tasks" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Activities</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-file" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Reports</p></a></li>
                        <li class="hideli"><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-cog" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Admin</p></a></li>
                        <li><a href="@Url.Action("Team", "Admin")"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span><p>Save View</p></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

    </header>

    <div id="body">
            @RenderBody()
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed. It was as simple as closing and opening visual studio.